# Is the phoneme /k/ in the word cube aspiated or unaspirated?

Tags: aspiration

I have a debate in class about the aspiration status of the phoneme /k/ in the word "cube". By the rule, it should be. However, some people's pronunciation with the sheet paper in front of the subject's mouth test make it move as if it is aspirated, but others don't, as it isn't. Does it depend on the dialect spoken by the subject? Does the subject's mother tongue (L1) have any influence? The tests were only performed on stand alone words, so there wasn't any conected speech.

Comment: The _phoneme_ is aspiration-agnostic, since aspiration is not by itself phonemically contrastive in English. What may or may not be aspirated is the sound itself, rather than the phoneme. Of course a person’s first language is likely to affect how they pronounce things, and it's common for, say, French people not to aspirate their initial consonants; but native English speakers consistently do so across all dialects I'm familiar with.

Comment: You hafta use the right test if you're gonna measure aspiration with sheet paper. First, you need a **contrast**, not just one example. So, use _cue_ and _skew_, both pronounced by the same speaker, and note the difference in paper wiggle, once you have the paper adjusted so there's wiggle. Everybody is likely to have different wiggle tension levels, though native English speakers will find more wiggle in _cue_ than in _skew_. Use a match or cigarette lighter (at the appropriate distance from the mouth, natch).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is the first sound /k/ in the word "confused" aspirated or unaspirated?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269798/is-the-first-sound-k-in-the-word-confused-aspirated-or-unaspirated)

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica I wonder if the /j/ changes whether it's aspirated or not? Is it /kjuːb/ or /kʰjuːb/?